# Curl not working on apache with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

I want to use `curl` on Apache with Ubuntu 16.04; for that I installed it using :

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

It says `curl is already the newest version (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.14)`.
But when I run my script it says :

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/html....
```

Comment: Need more info.  What is your script?  PHP?  Did you install `php5-curl`?

Comment: I think @ThomasWard is right, you missing some dependency on php modules not in the system. Read also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382539/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init

Answer (score 1):

`curl` is the command line program called `curl`, not the PHP bindings for `libcurl`.

You need to make sure you've installed `php5-curl` (`php-curl` on 18.04 and newer) and then restart your PHP / Apache2 server to pick up the now-present Curl plugin and library bindings for PHP.